# Dropdown in Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following HTML code:

```
<select id="prefix" style="height: 42px; position: relative; width: 280px; display: none;" name="prefix">
   <optgroup label="Summary">
        <option value="pre_arb">Pre-arb</option>
        <option value="post_arb">Post-arb</option>
        <option value="output">Output</option>
   </optgroup>
   <option value="individual">Individual</option>
</select>

<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li>
      <label class="multiselect-group">Summary</label>
  </li>
  <li class="group-option">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
           <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" style="display:none" value="pre_arb">
                 Pre-arb
           </label>
     </a>
 </li>
```

My goal is to choose a value from dropdown list, I have tried various methods for this including `Select` class. But I am getting error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'
```

In Firefox, whole of `Select` HTML and part of `List` is grayed out.

Can anyone help about how to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340680/selenium-how-can-i-make-webdriver-ignore-element-is-not-visible-error.

Comment: Well the `display` is `none`, so it is not visible and selenium wont be able to interact with it. You could use Java script to set your option.

Comment: Well only radio button is invisible, rest of the <label> and link <a> is visible and should be clickable. '<a href="javascript:void(0);">
           <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" style="display:none" value="pre_arb">
                 Pre-arb
           </label>
     </a>'

Comment: Select the `optgroup` and then find all elements with tag name `option` and choose the desired one from them; then perform a `click` operation. Something like: 

`next(e for e in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//optgroup[@label="Summary"]').find_elements_by_tag_name('option') if e.get_attribute('value') == 'post_arb')`