# selecting from a dropdown of a hidden element

Tags: python, selenium

```
<th id="id1" class="LockedColumnForTable" nowrap="nowrap" index="1" level="1" path="db" name="db" style="padding:0;" isLeaf="true" n="Date"><div id="id2"><select name="name1" id="id3" style="display: none;">
<option value="38478">27-Mar-2014</option>
<option value="38388">26-Mar-2014</option>
</select></div></th>
```

This is the code for the dropdown in the web ui. I need to select 26-Mar-2014.  I am using python selenium.

I wrote the code

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id3').style.display='block'")
```

But I get Javascript error when I run the code. Please advise what I am missing here.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340680/selenium-how-can-i-make-webdriver-ignore-element-is-not-visible-error

Answer (score 0):

It is far more advisable to perform the action which would result in the object being displayed (e.g. Mouse over event).

Forcing visibility with JavaScript does not prove the application actually works for a human user, and therefore invalidates the tests.

I have been automating for ten years and only once have I been forced to inject JavaScript when I failed to find a way of replicating the human interaction.