# Automate file upload using Selenium and ng-file-upload

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, automation, ng-file-upload

I have a project where I am uploading photos via [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I need to automate the upload process with selenium webdriver in Python.

my HTML element looks like this:

```
<element
    ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*"
    ngf-max-size="10MB" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-select="addPhoto($index, $file)">
    ...</element>
```

Uploading the element definitely works when doing it manually.  But I cannot find a way to automate this using Selenium in Python.  I have tried finding the element, then sending the keys of the image's absolute path, but that just puts the absolute path in the browser's search field (as if I typed "Command + F" on Mac)

Note that there is no

```
<input type="file"/>
```

with this method of uploading a file.

Any ideas how to do this in Python using Selenium? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There *has to be a file input* hidden which is implicitly responsible for the file upload. For instance, the [`angular-file-upload` DEMO page](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) has it hidden at the bottom of a page.

Here is a working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/")

# wait for the upload box to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[ngf-select]")))

# get a model
model = element.get_attribute("ng-model")

# find a file input by model
file_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[ngf-select][ng-model="%s"]' % model)

# upload an image
file_input.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/dr-evil-and-minion-laughing.png")
```

Results into:

[image]

Comment: You're right they are at the bottom of the page, but they are hidden, so I can't send them keys, do you know how I would access them?  I have been researching and it says I have to execute Javascript to set the css to make them visible, but I have my file inputs repeatable so there I don't know a way to access a single element and make it visible.

Comment: @northsideknight you are right, make them visible - see, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25725701/771848. If you have multiple hidden elements, find them all and make them visible one by one.