# Send_keys function does do its work as expected in Selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium

The following html code is resposible for uploading file and `element.send_keys(absfilepath)` does not work. after sending `click` to element it opens up the fileupload window in the os (Linux in my case) and I couldn't interact with it.

Tested with Chrome, Firefox, PhantomJS no result with any of them.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input value="" class="select-file-button" type="button">
</div>
```

which is attached to iQuery.ajaxFileUpload.js. Here is the result after file 
is uploaded manually:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <div class="ajax-fileupload" style="background-image: url(&quot;/Profishop/Temp/70a569b6747041bc88da3b74871afff7/Screenshot-2017-12-12%20Telegram%20Web.png&quot;);"><input type="button" class="delete-button"></div>
 </div>
```

Also in the source code I found the `input type="file"` element but it is called by a script and it not accessible in generated page.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <input type="file" class="afuProductImage" />
</div>
```

and this is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
               $(".afuProductImage").ajaxFileUpload({
               uploadHandler: "/aja/upload?id=70a569b6747041bc88da3b74871afff7&op=upload",
               deleteHandler: "/ajax/upload?op=deleteid=70a569b6747041bc88da3b74871afff7&name=",
               filePath: null,
               containerAttrs: {
               class: "ajax-fileupload"
                               },
                buttonAttrs: {
                value: ""
                 },
                });
               });//]]>
</script>
```

Is there a way to upload the file using selenium by sending it a javascript command?

Comment: `I couldn't interact with it` What did you try?

Comment: actually couldn't find a way to access the select file open window API, I no idea how to do it. there are some guides for windows OS but nothing on linux

Answer (score 0):

*The idea is to not click the element at all costs* to avoid the "File Upload" window opened.

Locate the `input` element with `type="file"` and just send the keys to it with the absolute path to the file you want to upload.

Comment: there is `input` element with `type="file"` in source-code but when i try to access it, the error states that element class is not available. there is a `script` that calls that input.

Comment: @King110 for starters, you can try making the element visible - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725701/771848. Is there a way for you to make the problem reproducible for us as well? May be share the URL to the webpage where you are doing it?..thanks.